# C : initializer element is not constant

Tags: c, io, fork, element

I'm learning `fork()` in `C` and I'm having these errors:

```
app.c:13:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
app.c:13:1: error: initializer element is not constant
app.c:15:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘if’
app.c:20:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘else’
app.c:26:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘else’
```

Here is the source code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int f;
pid_t pid;

char msga[] = "abcd";
char msgb[] = "wxyz";

f = open("toto", O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC|O_CREAT,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);

if ((pid = fork()) == -1) {
    perror("fork");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

else if (pid == 0) {
    wait(NULL);
    write(f, &msga, strlen(msga));
    close(f);
}

else {
    wait(NULL);
    write(f, &msgb, strlen(msgb));
    close(f);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap all of that (after the `#include` lines) inside a function!

```
int main(void)
{
 ...
}
```

You'll probably want to add a `return 0;` at the end there, too.

In a quick test here, I also needed to add:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
```

To get the declarations of `fork(2)` and `strlen(3)`, resepectively.